# To check file size in hadoop

Tags: unix, hadoop

i Need to check the size of file in hdfs and check if the file is less than 10KB then print error along with file name

```
Minsize=10
for Actualsize in `hadoop fs -du -h /path | cut -d" " -f1`
do
if [ $Actualsize -lt $Minsize ]; then
    echo "File generated incorrectly for $file : Filesize - $Actualsize KB "
    echo "Exiting from Script file size found less than 10KB"
  exit 1;
fi
done
```

Getting the error like
integer expression expected

Moreo over i need to print the filename as well File generated incorrectly for $file

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of hdfs fsck command to get the file sizes.

For e.g., when I execute hdfs fsck /tmp/ -files, then I get the following output:

```
 /tmp <dir>
 /tmp/100GB <dir>
 /tmp/100GB/Try <dir>
 /tmp/100GB/Try/1.txt 5 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
/tmp/100GB/_SUCCESS 0 bytes, 0 block(s):  OK
  /tmp/100GB/part-m-00000 107374182400 bytes, 800          block(s):  OK
 /tmp/100GB/part-m-00001._COPYING_ 44163923968 bytes, 330 block(s):
 /tmp/10GB <dir>
 /tmp/10GB/_SUCCESS 0 bytes, 0 block(s):  OK
  /tmp/10GB/part-m-00000 10737418300 bytes, 81 block(s):  OK
/tmp/1GB <dir>
/tmp/1GB/_SUCCESS 0 bytes, 0 block(s):  OK
/tmp/1GB/part-m-00000 1073741900 bytes, 9 block(s):  OK
  /tmp/1GB/part-m-00001 1073741900 bytes, 9 block(s):  OK
```

It recursively lists all the files under /tmp along with their sizes.

Now, to parse out the file with max size, you can execute the following command:

hdfs fsck /tmp/ -files | grep "/tmp/" | grep -v "" | gawk '{print $2, $1;}'  | sort -n 
This command does the following:

hdfs fsck /tmp/ -files - It runs HDFS file system check on the folder /tmp/ and seeks report for each of the files under /tmp/
grep "/tmp/" - It greps for /tmp/ (the folder which we want to search). This will give only files and folders under /tmp/
"grep -v """ - This removes the directories from the output (since we only want files)
gawk '{print $2, $1;}' - This prints the file size ($2), followed by the file name ($1)
sort -n - This does a numeric sort on the file size and the last file in the list should be the file with the largest size
You can pipe the output to tail -1 to get the largest file.

For e.g. I got output as:

107374182400 /tmp/100GB/part-m-0000

Comment: Is there a way to modiy in my own snippet

Comment: @user2672739: see edit link in the bottom of your post

Comment: I mean to say that i wanted to make changes in my script , solution to fix it

Answer (score 0):

> Getting the error like integer expression expected

That's because you use the option `-h` of the [`du`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.11/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du) command, and the *-h option will format file sizes in a "human-readable" fashion (e.g 64.0m instead of 67108864)*. This *"human-readable" fashion* is not recognized by the test command. Change to `Minsize=10240` and leave out the `-h`.

> Moreo over i need to print the filename as well File generated incorrectly for $file

For this you have to read the filename from the third column.

```
Minsize=10240
hadoop fs -du /path | while read Actualsize _ file
do
if [ $Actualsize -lt $Minsize ]; then
    echo "File generated incorrectly for $file: Filesize - $Actualsize"
    echo "Exiting from Script file size found less than 10 KB"
    exit 1
fi
done
```